# Apache Beam pipeline stuck indefinitely using Wait.on transform with JdbcIO

Tags: java, apache-beam, apache-beam-jdbcio

I have an Apache Beam pipeline that gets stuck indefinitely when using the `Wait.on` transform alongside `JdbcIO`. Here's a simplified version of my code, focusing on the relevant parts:

```java
PCollection<String> result = p.
    apply("Pubsub", PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription(/*...*/))
    .apply("Transform", ParDo.of(new MyTransformer()));

PCollection<Void> insert = result.apply("Inserting",
    JdbcIO.<String>writeVoid()
        .withDataSourceProviderFn(/*...*/)
        .withStatement(/*...*/)
        .withPreparedStatementSetter(/*...*/)
);

result.apply(Wait.on(insert))
    .apply("Selecting", new SomeTransform())
    .apply("PubsubMessaging", ParDo.of(new NextTransformer()));
p.run();
```

In the code, I'm using the `Wait.on` transform to make the pipeline wait until the `insert` transform (which uses JdbcIO to write data) is completed before executing the next steps. However, the pipeline gets stuck and doesn't progress further.

I've tried adding logging messages in my transforms to track the progress and identify where it's getting stuck, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the issue. I've also looked through multiple Stack Overflow posts on this topic, but none of them provided a successful solution for my problem.

Can anyone provide any insights or suggestions on how to debug and resolve this issue involving `Wait.on` and JdbcIO in my Apache Beam pipeline?

sample code https://github.com/j1cs/app-beam

**Update**: according to this discussion https://lists.apache.org/thread/z5phzd01nln6jnr5qn20sojqlj3tqqhd appears the problem is the implementation of pubsub using direct-runner. i haven't tested it yet using dataflow as a backend.